# Does this question really need five Star Trek tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7827/has-anyone-on-star-trek-traveled-into-the-future-without-a-future-intermediary) has a whopping five tags denoting it as a Star Trek question. Are they really necessary? Can't the question just be labeled [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) and be done with it? Or am I missing some reason that the question needs to be denoted as [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek), [star-trek-tng](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng), [star-trek-voyager](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-voyager), [star-trek-ds9](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-ds9), *and* [enterprise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enterprise)? Can we do away with some of these tags so that we can add, for example, [time-travel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel)?

Just wondering if there is a protocol I'm missing before I go mess everything up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I agree, so I've retagged it with just [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) and [time-travel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel).  It has to do with all of Star Trek; it's not specific to any of the sub-tags, so I don't think it needs any of them.  And it certainly does need time-travel.

Answer (score 10):

When I ask a question about a specific series of Star Trek, I use that series tag. But if my question is related to multiple series, or the universe at large, I use just the `star-trek` tag.

Answer (score -1):

That's quite a dilly of a pickle.  It is a time travel question, but it's a question that also covers all of the iterations of Star Trek.  I'd say leave it as is.  Either we need a feature request for more tags on a question, or we need some way to create tag hierarchies, so we could have each Star Trek show have their own tag, that also acts as a generic Star Trek tag.

Comment: You can use [tag:star-trek*] to get questions about any of the tags that match, whether searching or for an RSS feed (perhaps also the 'favourites', but I haven't tried that).  I would have no idea that this was possible if I hadn't seen a comment about it from @Gilles.  I think it's reasonable to say that it's not particularly discoverable.

Comment: That *seems* to work also for favorite tags.  I can't find any questions that have a star trek show tag without also having the generic star trek tag to confirm it works for the show tags.